# playing youtube links not working

Tags: iphone, youtube, media-player

Here is my code

```
- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString*)url frame:(CGRect)frame {  
    UIWebView * videoView;
    NSString* embedHTML = @"<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body {background-color: transparent;color: white;}</style></head><body style=\"margin:0\"><embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed></body></html>";  
    NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];  
    if(videoView == nil) {  
        videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];  
        [self.view addSubview:videoView];  
    }  
    [videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];  
}
```

so in viewDidLoad I call

```
[self embedYouTube:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mcjR3TsK4s&feature=g-logo&context=G2e376ceFOAAAAAAAAAA" frame:self.view.bounds];
```

I'm testing it in ipad2 ios 5.0 and it is an error

> -[_UIAppearance loadHTMLString:baseURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3ec3e63c 2012-01-15 22:50:22.158 test2[3853:707] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIAppearance
>   loadHTMLString:baseURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x3ec3e63c'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x380cf8bf 0x37c1b1e5 0x380d2acb 0x380d1945 0x3802c680 0x3513 0x3407 0x31bb07ff 0x31baef9d 0x31ba1941
>   0x31c13541 0x3241 0x31baf7eb 0x31ba93bd 0x31b77921 0x31b773bf
>   0x31b76d2d 0x37dfddf3 0x380a3553 0x380a34f5 0x380a2343 0x380254dd
>   0x380253a5 0x31ba8457 0x31ba5743 0x3029 0x2f84) terminate called
>   throwing an exception(gdb)

Thanks for helping

Comment: Do you get any warnings when compiling this app?

Comment: @Till   i copyed this code NSString* embedHTML = @"\ 
    <html><head>\ 
 <style type=\"text/css\">\ 
 body {\ 
 background-color: transparent;\ 
 color: white;\ 
 }\ 
 </style>\ 
 </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\ 
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \ 
 width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\ 
    </body></html>";      and xcode doesn't like symbol / so i deleted it. and it was no warmimgs

Comment: Define UIWebView *videoView = nil;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you defined variable like `UIWebView * videoView;` it's assumes that it refers to some memory. Usually it refers to nil and all works fine, but in your case it refers to another object and comparing `videoView == nil` won't work. To avoid it always declare variables and refer it to `nil` explicity.

```
UIWebView *videoView = nil;
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer  -  still makes me wonder why the compiler did not spit out a warning. Ow, actually, the analyzer would have warned but not the compiler.